# Change Alt Text for Multiple Form Control Checkboxes

Tags: forms, text, checkbox, controls, alt

Is there a way to update the alt text for multiple form control checkboxes at once using Excel VBA? I have about 20 check boxes on a worksheet {"Sheet1"} (Check Box 1, Check Box 2, ... Check Box 20) and need to change the text for all to = "In Progress". Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

"**Finding and Replacing in Text Boxes**

by Allen Wyatt
(last updated July 20, 2019)

```vb
Sub TextBoxReplace()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim sOld As String
    Dim sNew As String

    'Change as desired
    sOld = "Old string"
    sNew = "New string"
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        With shp.TextFrame.Characters
            .Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute( _
              .Text, sOld, sNew)
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

This macro steps through all the shapes in the worksheet (text boxes are shapes) and then replaces whatever is in the `sOld` variable with whatever is in the `sNew` variable."

From excelribbon.tips.net

Answer (score -1):

Disregard; I found a solution!  ^_^

**https://excelribbon.tips.net/T009264_Finding_and_Replacing_in_Text_Boxes.html**

Comment: Hello! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Aha, great feedback; I didn't consider that initially & have posted an updated comment.